# Forcing horizontal scrollbar and all child divs in one line

Tags: html, css

Good evening,

I would like a div which is **100% width of its parent** to expand only horizontally. If there are too many child elements for the current width, a HORIZONTAL scrollbar has to appear. Every child element has the same width (200px) and they all should be displayed in the same line.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="width-100-div">
        <div class="child">
        <div class="child">
        <div class="child">
        <div class="child">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this? ALL Divs with class "child" have to be displayed in ONE line, the same line, and when the line is too wide for its div there should be the possibility to scroll HORIZONTALLY.

Comment: `display: flex`?

Comment: ok if all child div should be 'inline' elements what you want is horizontal

Comment: oh my god yea I was talking about horizontal, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Make your inner elements inline-blocks and add this to the container (and close your DIV-tags...):

```
#width-100-div {
  overflow-x: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
#width-100-div {
  overflow-x: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="width-100-div">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`display: flex`** to achieve that. Follow the code below

```css
.parent {
 background-color: dodgerBlue;
 padding: 1em;
 width: 90%;
 display: flex;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.child {
 background-color: tomato;
 padding: 1em;
 margin-left: 0.5em;
 margin-right: 0.5em;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">1</div>
 <div class="child">2</div>
 <div class="child">3</div>
 <div class="child">4</div>
 <div class="child">5</div>
 <div class="child">6</div>
 <div class="child">7</div>
 <div class="child">8</div>
 <div class="child">9</div>
 <div class="child">10</div>
 <div class="child">11</div>
 <div class="child">12</div>
 <div class="child">13</div>
 <div class="child">14</div>
 <div class="child">15</div>
 <div class="child">17</div>
 <div class="child">18</div>
 <div class="child">19</div>
 <div class="child">20</div>
</div>
```

You can modify it to meet your requirement :)